# How can I retain spaces between words that don't contain numbers when splitting a multi-word string?

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to *split* a string by *space* but *leave names together*?

**Example:**

```
"1 23565 john smith 01/01/2021 another"
```

**Expected:**

```
string[] {"1", "23565", "john smith", "01/01/2021", "another"}
```

Names in this case are any word in the string that don't contain numbers. "Name" words are always preceded and succeeded by "number" words.

Comment: How would you define a name?  "name" means nothing to regex.  Do you mean a word with no numbers in it?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the base concept. Where do these data come from? Do you save them? If yes so change the split character and use `,` `|` `\t` (a TAB).

Comment: that's the problem. the data comes from a pdf with no formatting whatsoever, so i cant split the string by  TAB "," or "|", also the position of the fields changes so i cant use substring

Comment: @DanCsharpster the only pattern that i was able to find is that before and after the "name" there are always numbers. so i was trying to find some way to split the string before a letter shows up and after the last letter

Comment: We need more examples, we should find a good pattern. Can you paste some others?

Comment: @AlexDalzoto `also the position of the fields changes`,  if that's the case then how do you know what data is at what index etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = "1 23565 john smith 01/01/2021 another";

 string[] result = Regex.Split(source, @"(?<=\P{L})\s+|\s+(?=\P{L})");

 // Let's have a look:
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 1, 23565, john smith, 01/01/2021, another
```

Here I've put `(?<=\P{L})\s+|\s+(?=\P{L})` pattern:

```
(?<=\P{L})\s+ - look behind (not a letter) 
                then one or more whitespaces
|             - or
\s+(?=\P{L})  - one or more whitespaces and 
                then (look ahead) not a letter
```

Comment: Alex, if the string were `"1 23565 1X Y2 01/01/2021 another"` this would produce `["1", "23565", "1X Y2", "01/01/2021", "another"]`, but you said, "Names in this case are any word in the string that don't contain numbers".  By that definition `"1X"` and `"Y2"` are not names. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

*This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I'm going to focus on solving X instead of Y.*

No and yes.

There may be some Regex to do this for you, but that includes extra complexity and overhead. And I don't know regex well enough to offer an example.

If you try just a regular `string.split`, then you can't avoid splitting the name. However, if you know that the string will be formatted exactly the same way 100% of the time, you can concatenate the 2nd & 3rd instance of the split string back together, but it would be a manual process and it would break if you ever changed the string format.

```
string value = "1 23565 john smith 01/01/2021 another";
List<string> values = value.Split(" ");
values[2] += " " + values[3];
values.RemoveAt(3);
```

A better option might be to avoid this altogether by using [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or [XML](https://www.w3.org/XML/).

These are both data transfer specifications which allow you to keep different pieces of data separated while still transferring them together.

Examples:

```
// JSON
{
  id: 1,
  randomNumber: 23565,
  name: "john smith",
  hireDate: "01/01/2021",
  description: "another"
}

// XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<id>1</id>
<randomNumber>23565</randomNumber>
<name>john smith</name>
<hireDate>01/01/2021</hireDate>
<description>another</description>
```

As you might notice, XML has a bit more complexity and character count to it. It's still a very popular method of data transport, but the smaller size and easier to understand format of JSON are causing people to convert more projects over to JSON.

There are plenty of existing libraries to convert data into and out of both of these formats, so you don't have to do any of that. The C# language itself has some conversion for these formats built-in, but that has limits and caveats that tend to make people use the external libraries (commonly found on NuGet).

And with the generally fast internet speeds people have for even their home and cell use, the small amount of extra overhead needed for these formats generally doesn't outweigh the ease of using the data formats.

Edit:

As per the comments, the OP could get multiple names in the string. Here's a modification to the "Split" option I first suggested that can handle this format as well. Unfortunately, it does expect a date format, so changing the `if` statement to break on other conditions could be set if the format changes further.

```
string value = "1 23565 john smith jane doe doc brown 01/01/2021 another";
List<string> values = value.Split().ToList();

for (int i = 2; i < values.Count;)
{
  values[i] += " " + values[++i];
  values.RemoveAt(i);

  if (values[i].IndexOf("/") != -1)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

This provides a result of:
values = {"1", "23565", "john smith", "jane doe", "doc brown", "01/01/2021", "another"};

Also, I consider this an XY problem because the tag of `regex`. I also thought the string was a response from another API or a query from a client side UI, which is why I suggested converting to JSON or XML. A comment from the OP below explains why that's not possible.

Comment: It would be great to use JSON or XML but the date comes from a governament website and they only make it avaliable as a PDF. Also i can't concatenate the 2nd and 3rd fields because sometimes the "name" has 3, 4 or more "names"

Comment: @AlexDalzoto, ugh, that sounds ugly. You should probably add to the question that you are possibly getting more than one name in the string, including more examples. That's going to significantly change how things are handled.

Comment: Why do you view this as an X-Y problem considering that the OP did not suggest a method of solution?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, the `regex` tag was included. IME, that means people want to focus on that type of solution, even if it's not explicitly stated in the question. And yes, I've been "yelled at" in comments for answering a question and not following the tags.

Answer (score 1):

We are asked to split the string on spaces other than spaces between names, where a name is any word in the string that does not contain a number.

One can split on matches of the following:

```
(?<=(?:^| )\S*\d\S*) | (?=\S*\d\S*(?: |\z))
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/tester/CKJGNI19911)

The matches are shown below by the party hats.

```
1 23565 john smith 01/01/2021 another
 ^     ^          ^          ^

1 23565 john smith1 01/01/2021 another
 ^     ^    ^      ^          ^

1 23565 1john smith 01/01/2021 another
 ^     ^     ^     ^          ^

1 23565 jo1hn sm1th 01/01/2021 another
 ^     ^     ^     ^          ^
```

The regular expression has the following elements:

```
(?<=        # begin positive lookbehind
  (?:^| )   # match beginning of string or space in a non-capture group
  \S*\d\S*  # match 1+ chars other than whitespace followed by
            # a digits followed by 1+ chars other than whitespace
)           # end negative lookbehind
[ ]         # match a space
|           # or
[ ]         # match a space
(?=         # begin positive lookahead
  \S*\d\S*  # match 1+ chars other than whitespace followed by
            # a digits followed by 1+ chars other than whitespace
  (?: |\z)  # match a space or end of string in a non-capture group
)           # end positive lookahead
```

I've put each of the spaces in a character class (`[ ]`) to make them visible.

This regular expression makes use of the fact that `C#`'s regex engine supports variable-length lookbacks, a feature most regex engines lack.

Depending on requirements, one may want to replace `\S*\d\S*` with `[a-z\d]*\d[a-z\d\*`, possibly with the case-indifferent flat (`i`) set.